# Phrase for the elder of my younger sisters?

Tags: phrase-requests, kinship-terms

If i have two sisters younger than me, how can i refer to the elder one of them? "Younger sister" is ambiguous, but "older sister" is inaccurate. "Elder one of my younger sisters" is long and clumsy. I'm a guy, btw.

Is there a shorter phrase to say this?

Comment: There is no specific name for that particular sibling which would make it clear to the listener that you have two younger sisters and you're referring to the elder of the two. There are two points of age-comparison: she's younger than you but older than the youngest. 'Middle sister' could be taken to mean that you have three sisters.

Comment: How about just "*my **oldest** sister*"? And the other one is your "***youngest** sister*", of course. And they're both your *younger* sisters.

Comment: @Dan Bron: What if he has a sister who is older than he is?  How does "oldest" convey the meaning "the elder of two sisters who are younger than I"?

Comment: @TRomano “My older little sister” (for some reason, _elder_ just sounds very strange to me here) would make both points of comparison clear: she’s a little sister, so she’s younger than me; and she’s the _older_, which means that there is exactly one other little sister who is younger than her. Similarly, “my oldest little sister” would unambiguously say that I have at least three little sisters, of which this one is the oldest.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet: "little sister" is certainly idiomatic, but "older little sister" is jarring. In my experience with families having three or more children, I've never heard anyone attempt to express in a single phrase the particular relationship the OP has in mind. It usually goes something like this: *I have two younger sisters|brothers|siblings. X is 15 and Y is 12.

Answer (score 1):

"Mamie is my next-younger sister; Sally is the baby.

Answer (score 1):

You can call your younger sibling, who's older than her smaller sister, the **second-youngest sister**.

> closeness to my littlest sister. Since I was her big brother, she thought I was the greatest thing. [When my second-youngest sister,](https://www.google.com/search?q=second%20youngest%20child&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&oq=second%20youngest%20&aqs=chrome.5.69i57j0l5.11085j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22second%20youngest%20sister%22&tbm=bks&start=20) Pat, was born, I was ten or eleven, so the last thing I wanted to be doing was holding and cuddling a baby.